# Flow control with async without throwing Errors

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am having an issue where Intellij is warning me about *'throw' of exception caught locally*. After doing some digging on why this is not ok it makes sense, errors should not be used for flow control. The problem I am facing though is in async I cannot reject the promise without throw something locally and I get the warning.

Some of my example code.

Top level takes in the request and awaits for the response from the controller:

```
Router.post("/",  async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let itemController = new ItemController(req.body);
        let response = await itemController.request();

        res.send(response); 
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: error});
    }
});
```

The controller takes in the request and awaits on other functions to get some data.

```
async request() {
    try {
        await isValidItem();
        return await this.initialize();
    } catch(error) {
        throw error; 
    }
}
```

Then I have a function which gets manufacturer ID for this item and I run into my problem. If the SQL query doesn't fail and nothing is in the response I need to throw a local error so that the request can fail gracefully. and send a proper 500 error to the client.

```
async queryManufacturerID() {
    try {
        let result = await this.queryManufacturerID(this.itemID, this.brand);

        if (result === false) {
            throw new Error("this item has no manufacturer ID");
        } else {
            this.manufacturerID = result["manufacturerItemID"];
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

My problem is I know I can adjust this so other functions that get a reply from this can know that this function failed without a error but that would have to happen in this entire chain to prevent throwing locally. Seems like a lot of bloat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that makes this code bloaty and the IDE complain is not throwing errors, but this:

```
 try {
   //...
 } catch (error) {
   throw error;
 }
```

It's a no op. You can safely remove it without changing the logic.

The only case where you should use `catch` is when you actually plan to handle the error and get the execution back on track.

> After doing some digging on why this is not ok it makes sense, errors should not be used for flow control

I disagree. Errors are a part of proper flow control, they allow you to handle unplanned things. Throwing an error if something unexpected occured makes sense, also in this case.

Comment: "Errors are a part of proper flow control, they allow you to handle unplanned things." I think that people who argue against using exceptions for flow control would agree with you. What they object to, I think, is using exceptions to handle things that aren't _exceptional_. Suppose, for example, that instead of returning `null`, `Array#find` threw an exception when no element was found. On the other hand, a server returning 500 easily fits the definition of exceptional, and throwing an exception for it would, I think, make sense to just about everybody.

Comment: This was extremely helpful Jonas Wilms. I was confused by the removal of try/catch because what would throw the error but await automatically will reject the error being thrown from the previous function. 

This also removed the IDE error. Thanks!